# Linux: Appending values into files, to the end of particular lines, and at the bottom of the file if there is on "key"

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

I have one file, file1, that has values like so:

```
key1|value1|
key2|value2|
key3|value3|
```

I have another file, file2, that has key based values I would like to add to add to file1:

```
key2 value4
key3 value5
key4 value6
```

I would like to add values to file1 to lines where the "key" matches, and if there is no "key" in file1, simply adding the new key & value to the bottom:

```
key1|value1|
key2|value2|value4|
key3|value3|value5|
key4|value6|
```

It seems like this is something that could be done with 2 calls to awk, but I am not familiar enough with it.  I'm also open to using bash or shell commands.

---

**UPDATE**

I found this to work

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {print $1,$2,a[$1];delete a[$1]}END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: It can be done with one call to awk. Read file2 first, put its contents into an array whose keys are the `key` column. Then read file1, and when the key matches, append the value to the line, and remove it from the array. In the `END` block, print all the remaining entries in the array.

Comment: There's also the `join` command.

Comment: assuming files are using the same delimiters `join -j1 -a1 -a2 -t\| <(sort -t\| -k1 f01.txt) <(sort -t\| -k1 f02.txt)`

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I developed something per your suggestion and updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

The only deviation from the desired output is that keys from file1 that are not in file2 are not known AOT, so they are printed at the end to keep things semi-online:

```
awk -v first=data1.txt -f script.awk data2.txt
```

```awk
BEGIN {
    OLD=FS
    FS="|"
    while (getline < first)
        table[$1] = $0
    OFS=FS
    FS=OLD
}


!($1 in table) {
    queue[$1] = $0
}

$1 in table {
    id=$1
    gsub(FS, OFS)
    sub(/[^|]*\|/, "")
    print table[id] $0 OFS
    delete table[id]
}

END {
    for (id in table)
        print table[id]

    for (id in queue) {
        gsub(FS, OFS, queue[id])
        print queue[id] OFS
    }
}
```

```
key2|value2|value4|
key3|value3|value5|
key1|value1|
key4|value6|
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the LOL answer ... ha ha . I basically loop over both keeping track of them and sort ... silly'ish , probably not even something you would want to use bash for perhaps ..

```
declare -a checked
checked=()

file="/tmp/file.txt"
> "${file}"

while IFS= read -r line1 ;do

    key1=$(echo $line1 | cut -d'|' -f1)

    if ! grep -qi ${key1} "/tmp/file2.txt" ; then
        echo "$line1" >> "${file}"
        continue
    fi

    while IFS= read -r line2 ;do

        key2=$(echo $line2 | cut -d' ' -f1)

        if ! grep -qi ${key2} "/tmp/file1.txt" ; then
            if ! [[ "${checked[@]}" =~ $key2 ]] ;then
                echo "$(echo $line2| awk '{print $1"|"$2}')|" >> "${file}"
                checked+=(${key2})
                continue
            fi
        fi

        if [[ "$key2" == "$key1" ]] ;then
            echo "${line1}$(echo $line2 | cut -d' ' -f2-)|" >> "${file}"
            continue
        fi

    done < "/tmp/file2.txt"
done < "/tmp/file1.txt"

sort -k2 -n ${file}
[[ -f "${file}" ]] && rm -f "${file}"
```

Output:

```
key1|value1|
key2|value2|value4|
key3|value3|value5|
key4|value6|
```